# missing end to balance this if statement

Tags: git, bash, shell, unix, fish

i try to add this lines to my .bash-profile

```
if [ -f "$(brew --prefix)/opt/bash-git-prompt/share/gitprompt.sh" ];then
 source "$(brew --prefix)/opt/bash-git-prompt/share/gitprompt.sh"
fi
```

but I get this error

```
Missing end to balance this if statement
.bash_profile (line 2): if [ -f "$(brew --prefix)/opt/bash-git-       prompt/share/gitprompt.sh" ]; then
                    ^
from sourcing file .bash_profile
called on standard input
```

Dose anyone have an idea why?
I have the code from here
https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt

Comment: Why is this question tagged "fish"? Are you trying to source your `.bash_profile` from the fish shell? Fish is a different shell with different syntax; it's not compatible with bash.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've removed the tag

Comment: Still, the `.bash_profile (line 2):` looks like the format `fish` uses for error messages. Are you sure you're not sourcing your `.bash_profile` from `fish`?

Comment: Don't remove the tag; it's completely relevant, as the error message you post comes from `fish`, not `bash`.

Comment: @Arthur The problem is, you are running `fish`, not `bash`. The `gitprompt.sh` script is not relevant to `fish`. Under no circumstances should you be trying to source `.bash_profile` inside a `fish` session.

Comment: should I  try to source in bash?

Comment: You can -- but then the setup will apply only to the bash shell. If you then invoke `fish` from `bash`, it will inherit environment variables, but if `gitprompt.sh` is configuring your shell prompt, the method to do that in `fish` is going to be completely different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although the linked repository contains a script for `fish`, the README does not provide any directions for how to *use* that script. Not having used `fish` in several years, I *think* what you want to do is add

```
if status --is-login
  source (brew --prefix)"/opt/bash-git-prompt/share/gitprompt.fish"
end
```

to `~/.config/fish/config.fish` instead. The `if status` command prevents the file from being unnecessarily sourced if you aren't starting an interactive shell.

Comment: it's working, but get this yet:    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/gitstatus.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: You also need to either copy `gitprompt.py` from the bash-git-prompt installation to `~/.gitprompt`, or add something like `set __GIT_PROMPT_DIR (brew --prefix)"/opt/bash-git/prompt/share/"` to your `config.fish` file.

Answer (score 10):

This error message:

```
Missing end to balance this if statement
.bash_profile (line 2): if [ -f "$(brew --prefix)/opt/bash-git-       prompt/share/gitprompt.sh" ]; then
                    ^
from sourcing file .bash_profile
called on standard input
```

is generated by the `fish` shell.

The `.bash_profile` file is intended only to be executed (sourced) by the `bash` shell. `fish` is a different shell, with different syntax; it's not compatible with `bash`.

If you're using `fish` as your interactive shell, and you want some commands to be executed automatically when you start a new shell, you'll need to translate the bash-specific commands to `fish` syntax and add them to your `fish` startup file. (Not a lot of people use `fish`, so providers of software packages aren't likely to provide startup commands in `fish` syntax -- but this package apparently does; see [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39497441/827263).)